# HTML video showing weird black lines

Tags: css, html

I'm having an extremely strange issue with an HTML that has 3 videos on it. I'm using videojs for the videos, and all videos have been converted to three different formats to ensure cross-browser compat.

Having said that, when the videos are played, strange black lines appear on the bottom, or on the right of the videos (This even changes across browsers!!).

I have absolutely no clue where this lines come from, as they don't appear on CSS at all.

Here's the link to show you what I'm talking about:
http://tomascamusso.com/helpme

PS: In case it has become a part of the video itself, is there any common software to edit these videos?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to add my two pence: they're green for me, and the left-hand box has a green line at the bottom before playing any video.

Comment: I can confirm the observations by Bojangles. Same behavior here in FF as well.

Answer (score 2):

The line is in the background image which the video is overlayed on.

http://tomascamusso.com/helpme/img/hang_on_to_your_assets.png

Now I see the image is hidden when the video is played (display: none;). However it does look like the end of the video the still image from the feed was using the same background image.. worth looking into.

[image] - here is a screenshot.